# gunicorn: error: unrecognized arguments: --capture-output

Tags: python, gunicorn

I was trying to set up [Mimic Recording Studio](https://github.com/MycroftAI/mimic-recording-studio) with docker compose up but was met with the following error.

```
mrs-backend | usage: gunicorn [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]
mrs-backend | gunicorn: error: unrecognized arguments: --capture-output
mrs-backend exited with code 2
```

I am not sure whether I am on the right track of debugging but here's start_prod.sh:

```
gunicorn -w $WEBWORKERS -b 0.0.0.0:$APIPORT app:app -c gunicorn_conf.py --capture-output
```

and gnuicorn_conf.py

```
accesslog = 'logs'
loglevel = 'debug'
access_log_format = \
    '%(h)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s "%(r)s" %(s)s %(b)s "%(f)s" "%(a)s"'
```

Does anyone here happened to know how to solve this error?